# Retrieving raw status output from solr admin

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I want to write a script to compare results from a DataImportHandler to earlier results in an ETL process. The url I use in solr is:

```
http://HOSTNAME:PORT/solr/#/CORENAME/dataimport//dataimport
```

The Raw Status-Output has a nice JSON output with the information I need (documents fetched, etc) but I can't find anyway to return just this JSON output. Is there some argument I can give the URL or something? As it is I can't parse the page for the info I need.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) to get the state of the index.

If you set `numTerms=0` you get a minimal output, with last index time.

In order to get json output, you can append `wt=json&json.nl=map` to your SOLR request querystring.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with: `http://<host>:<port>/solr/dataimport?command=status&wt=json`

If you want a pretty-printed output, pipe the body of the response to `python -mjson.tool`